# problems encoding 1080p60fps MTS files with ffmpeg to DNxHD proxy; plays too slow in NLE compositor window.

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding

I was advised to encode my HD files with ffmpeg to DNxHD proxy with 220M bitrate rather then 45M so the image doesnt have too much artifacts.  I reduced the framerate to 29.97 fps when I encoded the clips and the project is also 29.97 fps.

The minute I apply an effect to my video track, playback is choppy in the compositor window (Cinelerra-CV) and I need to evaluate the clip with effects and see the motion in real-time.  My computer is 4 core AMD 3.4 GHz with 12G memory.  Ubuntu LTS 10.04.4 with desktop effects OFF. Decent Sata2 drives.

I don't want to re-encode my original clips at this point, so instead I was stuck rendering parts of the project to mpeg4 since it seems faster so I can add a couple of more effects.  But some other clips that didnt need anymore effects were rendered to RGBa uncompressed to preserve quality.  Now I dont know what to encode my final project to!!  Its a potential mess! Anyone has an idea how to proceed?

And for the future, what the heck should I be encoding to next time?? (for Cinelerra).  I'm having a hard time finding help in IRC etc, I hope there is a happy ending!

Comment: ok here is more info. that could be useful: I am using ffmpeg 4.05.1-1 ubuntu 10.04 repo.

Comment: the "recipe" I used was:  `code` ffmpeg -i input.MTS -b 220M -s 1920x1080 -r 29.97 -vcodec dnxhd -an output.mov `code`                                _           sample clip properties are: quicktime for linux ac3 44100 16bit DNXHD 29.97 1920X1080 2 min36s=4.0G   If someone could also confirm wether proxy files are meant to be furthur rendered or not before the final render...

Comment: Tara, welcome, please provide the ffmpeg output and the command you typed, this way we can know all about the input and the output files.